# MongoDB C# query for timestamp less than the current time

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to return documents from the collection where id = 1 and date created is less than the current time.

I tried this, but it isn't working:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection("test");   
var time = DateTime.Now;
var query2 = new QueryDocument
{
   { "id", 1},
   {{"created_on", {"$lt",time}}
};
```

What's wrong with this query?

Comment: What do your dates in `time` look like from the mongo shell? Do they present as `ISODate(..)` or something else? Good to add this to your question.

Comment: You're question title is about using "gt", yet the code uses `"$lt"`?

Comment: what type is `database`?

Answer (score 3):

You need an embedded document for the `$lt` sub-object, but you forgot to create it:

```
var query = new QueryDocument {
  { "id", 1 },
  { "created_on", new BsonDocument { { "$lt", time } } }
}
```

Also consider using the `Query` builder, which might make things simpler:

```
var query = Query.And(
  Query.EQ("id", 1),
  Query.LT("created_on", time)
);
```