# Query MongoDb for a datetime value less than NOW

Tags: mongodb, datetime

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405220/mongodb-c-sharp-query-for-timestamp-less-than-the-current-time) question addressess generating a query from C#, but how does one generate a comparision value equivalent to GetDate() (SQL Server) in MongoDB

i.e. I would like to express a JSON query like this:

```
{
Expiration: {$lte:  Now())},
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the Javascript function `new Date()`:

```
db.collection.find({ Expiration: { $lte: new Date() } })
```

The Mongo shell is just a Javascript shell, so you can, in principle, use any Javascript method.

Comment: Is "new Date()" generating "now" for the client or "now" for the server?  That's an important distinction I think

Comment: new Date() generating current date for server. My suggestion never use new Date() from client app for creating query parameters, use of new Date() at server side is a safe approach.

Comment: I tried with $$NOW and its not working
db.collection.find({ Expiration: { $lte: "$$NOW" } })

Comment: @khush it is because it needs to be inside the `aggregation` pipeline

Answer (score 4):

You can use any javascript function in query of mongo.

Try this :

```
db.collection.find({"Expiration":{"$lte": new Date()}})
```